# Changed user folder name and got several problems

Tags: windows, windows-10

Because my user folder name had a space in it, I had to change its name to one without spaces [some commands in hadoop wouldn't work because of this].My OS is Windows 10.
I followed all the steps mentioned in this link http://tunecomp.net/rename-user-profile-folder-in-windows-10-c-users/, and apparently everything was working.
However, I ran into several issues:

1. I can't click on the windows start up icon, or the search button, in the taskbar. They don't open.
2. When I click in any shortcut, or in browser icons, etc, I get messages like: 'unauthorized access', or, 'couldn't find path to (path with old username shows up}

Did I miss something? Do I need to do something else to fix this?
Thank you so much.